# Running "CLI"-type Docker images from inside other Docker containers without compromising security?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Context:**

Some authors package their applications as self-contained Docker images which can be run in "ethereal" containers like a CLI tool. For example:
`docker run --rm amazon/aws-cli --version`

These "CLI"-type images don't run as services/daemons. They often immediately exit after running. They might not be network-aware and often just take some input data from the shell and return output. They are essentially "one-shot" commands which is why I call them "CLI"-type images.

One example might be [aws-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli).

These are very useful for running apps from your host shell without worrying about installing dependencies etc., however the trouble comes when you want to use these images *inside another Docker container*. If I understand correctly, there is no simple/elegant/secure way to do this.

The current choices are (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Use multi-stage builds to `COPY` binaries from your CLI-type image to your existing Docker container. This might not be possible if your CLI tool has lots of dependencies or requires a specific environment in which to run.
2. Install Docker inside your existing Docker container and run your CLI-type image. (Docker in Docker)
3. Bind mount the Docker socket from the host to inside your existing Docker container and run your CLI-type image. (Docker out of Docker)
4. SSH to the host from inside your existing container and run the CLI-type image from the host.
5. Use the Docker API from inside your container to communicate with Docker running on the host and run your CLI image that way.
6. Create an API for your CLI image which will expose it on the network. Ingest request data, run your CLI image, and spit out the result via as an API response.

All of those solutions are (very) sub-optimal. Most have serious security concerns. All of them have a huge amount of friction.

I would like to see a way of essentially "piping" data between Docker containers, whereby you could run these CLI-type images from within other Docker containers as easily as if you were running them from your host machine.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you've pretty much listed out the options.  Also remember, on native Linux, if you can launch a container at all then you can pretty easily root the entire host.  I might make your program's primary distribution mechanism be a language- or distribution-native package – the AWS CLI is distributed as a binary in a tar file, and that could be included in an image – and offer a Docker image of a CLI tool as a convenient secondary distribution mechanism.